# Jquery to insert src attribute of iframes to be their respective id's

Tags: jquery

I am trying to dynamically add the src attribute to iframes, taken from their respective id's.

Here is what I am working with (using improper use of 'this' but you should get what I am trying to do.)

```
$(this).parent().find("iframe").attr('src', http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + $(this).attr('id'));
```

my iframe code looks something like this:

```
<iframe id = "XpOPKZB8dgY" src=""></iframe>
```

some more context if it helps:

```
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("iframe").attr('src', '');   
        $(".details").slideUp();   
        $("a.date").click(function() {   
            var key = $(this).parent().attr('class');  
            $(this).parent().children("div").slideToggle('slow');    
            $(this).parent().find("iframe").attr('src', "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + $(this).attr('id');                    
            $(document.body).animate({    
                'scrollTop':   $(this).offset().top    
            },   1000);    
        });  
    });

</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Missing a quote before 'http'?

Comment: I'm not clear on what your question is.  However I can see you are missing the leading quote on your URL in attr()

Comment: are you sure the second parameter in the attr method is correct? you seem to be missing quotation marks

Comment: .attr('src', "http:....) here? I am confused should the whole second parameter be in quotes or something?

Comment: the  $(this).attr('id') is coming up undefined for me

Comment: OMG I love stackoverflow!  You people are too frickin helpful (if this sounds sarcastic on the interwebs it is not, Thank you)

Comment: I think `$(this)` is coming up undefined for you because the keyword `this` is being used an incorrect location. Many jQuery developers will assign `$(this)` to a variable (for example, the first line inside of your click handler), and then use that variable, in place of `this`.

Comment: you need to do $(this).parent().find("iframe").attr("id")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$(this).parent().find("iframe").each(function(i) {
    var src = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + $(this).attr('id')
    $(this).attr('src', src);
});
```

Comment: It is and it works!  I will accept when it lets me.  Quick js noob question, what is the 'i' in function(i) for?

Comment: the i is not needed here ... see http://api.jquery.com/visual/? and search for "each" ...

Comment: your right +1, did it used to be a compulsory parameter in an older version? i am positive that when I first started using it the indexer was compulsory

Comment: it's needed if you use it .each(function(i,val) { console.log(i); $(val).text(); )}); i = index, val = domElement ;)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to fix your jQuery, your just missing a quotation mark:

```
$(this).parent().find("iframe").attr('src', "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + $(this).attr('id'));
```

Then I would try executing this JavaScript, once you have reassigned the src value to the iFrame:

```
document.getElementById('XpOPKZB8dgY').contentWindow.location.reload();
```

I didn't test this, but it should work. :)

Hope that helps,
spryno724

Comment: I am very confused about this quotation mark thing.... I pasted your code next to mine and it looks identical to me...

Comment: This works but the reload is not needed ... reassigning the src on the iframe triggers a reload

Comment: @Bobby Borszich Oh... really? Neat. I didn't know that. @Zack L. I was referring to the first code snippet you pasted in, which was missing the quotation mark.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/THnTb/

```
    $("iframe").each(function() {
        $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + $(this).attr('id'));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing parenthesis on the line you apply the src back to the iframe.
Also pulling the id from the iframe might require the same syntax as applying src.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("iframe").attr('src', '');   
        $(".details").slideUp();   
        $("a.date").click(function() {   
            var key = $(this).parent().attr('class');  
            $(this).parent().children("div").slideToggle('slow'); 

            var newSrc = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + 
              $(this).parent().find("iframe").attr('id'); 

            $(this).parent()
              .find("iframe")
              .attr(
                'src', newSrc 
               ); // << Missing Here                    
            $(document.body).animate({    
                'scrollTop':   $(this).offset().top    
            },   1000);    
        });  
    });
```

Comment: thanks, I caught that when I was looking for my missing quote mark ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not refering to the iframe `id`, you need to refer to it, the same way you already did to set the `src` attribute:

```
$(this).parent().find("iframe").attr('src', "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + $(this).parent().find("iframe").attr('id'));
```

Comment: guesse I didn't give enough context... this didnt work for me since there are multiple iframes within the parent... (unless I am confused which is likely)